# Media query CSS not working

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I am trying to do a media query to hide some text when i apply a class due to making it responsive, i normally use foundation but i need a custom media query.

It seems to not be applying.

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 992px) {
    .hideMediaQuery{display:none !important;}
}
```

Here is my class i am trying to apply it to:

```
 <div class="large-12 columns ProductDropdown left">
     <p class="hideMediaQuery">RACES</p>
     <label>
         <p>TESTEST</p>
     </label>       
 </div>
```

Anybody know why it is not working? I have just put it in style tags at the top of the page to test it before i put it in a style-sheet is this the reason?

Any advice would help.

Comment: Your code is perfectly valid and should work, even in a `<style>` tag. Can you provide us the relevant HTML? (`<head>` par and the line where you're using `.hide-for-text`)

Comment: Try pasting that code in the **bottom** of the page - I'm guessing that this code is being overridden

Comment: We'd need a demo to be sure. Try putting it at the bottom, as media queries are still part of the cascade ... although `!important` would normally trump anything.

Comment: I have inserted my class i am trying to make it to in the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have css classes written as follows:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 992px) {
    .hide-for-text{display:none !important;}
}

.hide-for-text{display:block !important;}
```

...the code in the media query will be overridden and hence won't work.

**[DEMO 1](http://jsfiddle.net/26qv3LjL/)**

Media Queries should generally be placed at the bottom of the CSS file to overcome this problem.

**[(WORKING) DEMO 2](http://jsfiddle.net/26qv3LjL/1/)**